# Looping over an Enum is null

Tags: c#, loops

I am following this tutorial (https://code-maze.com/factory-method/) to learn more about Factory patterns in C#. I have the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using FactoryPattern.Interfaces;

namespace FactoryPattern
{
    public class AirConditioner
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Actions, AirConditionerFactory> _factories;

        public AirConditioner()
        {
            _factories = new Dictionary<Actions, AirConditionerFactory>();

            foreach(Actions action in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Actions)))
            {
                var factory = (AirConditionerFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(
                                "FactoryMethod." + Enum.GetName(typeof(Actions), action) + "Factory"));

                _factories.Add(action, factory);
            }
        }

        public IAirConditioner ExecuteCreation(Actions action, double temperature) => _factories[action].Create(temperature);
    }
}
```

My Actions Enum is as follows:

```
namespace FactoryPattern
{
    public enum Actions
    {
        Cooling,
        Warming
    }
}
```

My Cooling/Warming factories are like this:

```
namespace FactoryPattern
{
    public class CoolingFactory : AirConditionerFactory
    {
         public override IAirConditioner Create(double temperature) => new CoolingManager(temperature);
    }
}
```

When I run the code I get an error on the line `foreach(Actions action...` because 'action' is null. Am I missing something really obvious here?

Comment: can you share the error message? It seems more likely that the null error is happening in the line..

Comment: @Chris "The name action does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Do you have types FactoryMethod.CoolingFactory and FactoryMethod.WarmingFactory? Your code has different namespace, FactoryPattern.

Comment: Thank you @pakeha_by good spot, I've changed all the namespaces to be the same and confirm yes I do have CoolingFactory and WarmingFactory - I will update my question to show these

Comment: agree with @pakeha_by. With Type.GetType() you are trying to create an instance of  "FactoryMethod.CoolingFactory" class. But the full name should be "FactoryPattern.CoolingFactory". You should change the "FactoryMethod." string.

Comment: When you get an NRE it is helpful to break down compound lines of code so that it is easier to tell exactly what is null. In your case, the NRE is coming from `Activator.CreateInstance()` because you are trying to create a type that does not exist. The type doesn't exist because it has the wrong namespace (as others have already mentioned) so `Type.GetType()` is returning null. You can mitigate the problem where strings don't match names in your code by using `nameof()`. See fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7LDysY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in the Namespace provided in the var Factory in the main method.

change the word "FactoryMethod." to your Application Namespace "FactoryPattern".

```
var factory = (AirConditionerFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(
                                "FactoryPattern." + Enum.GetName(typeof(Actions), action) + "Factory"));
```

In my case I had saved the Factory Classes in a separate folder so I had to change it respectively...

```
var factory = (AirConditionerFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("AirConditioner.Factories." + Enum.GetName(typeof(Actions), action) + "Factory"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"FactoryMethod." + Enum.GetName(typeof(Actions), action) + "Factory"
```

Your namespace looks like "`FactoryPattern`", not "`FactoryMethod`". Are you sure you're creating correct full namespace in that string concatenation?